# Accessing salesforce API from cross domain

Tags: force.com-sites

We have created a site in salesforce which has access to all our API's and we are trying to use this site from an off platform application. We have added off platform applications base url into the CORS whitelist, but still we are getting CORS error when trying to access this.

Comment: Please add the error message with stack trace and exception details for better debugging.